# Can a "monotonically increasing" series of integers also have a region where it is constant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

> Can a "monotonically increasing" series of integers also have a region where it is constant?

I ask because [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotoneIncreasing.html) seems to say no, but [other sources](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monotonic_increasing) seem to permit it?

The context is that some old documentation on no longer supported software describes a configuration parameter as being a monotonically increasing sequence of integers.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on definition.

Comment: As you noted, terminology varies; compare *increasing*: $x_i \le x_{i+1}$ with *strictly increasing*: $x_i \lt x_{i+1}$

Comment: Thanks T. I've given two, what do mathematicians think? Are there contexts that favour a particular definition?

Comment: define what you mean by "monotonically increasing"; then you'll get the answer.

Comment: Hi @utobi, I'm trying to work out what "they" meant.

Comment: In my experience, monotonically increasing means the same as strictly increasing, but [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) disagrees.

Comment: *I'm trying to work out what "they" meant* --- What others are implicitly saying is that this is not something like a computer science technical term that might have only been in existence a few decades and whose meaning has been standardized (especially given that CS research, until probably the 1990s if not later, was mostly concentrated in a handful of countries). These defined notions go back several centuries in textbooks in many dozens of countries, and have evolved in many different ways depending on the specific mathematical area, culture, and level (school, college, professional).

Comment: Interestingly in light of what @Jaap Scherphuis said, my experience has been the opposite, namely "monotonically increasing" means "nondecreasing". So even in this small corner of the mathematical universe you're getting two different things for what "they" mean. But my experience is mostly with monotone functions, such as in real analysis, where a bounded variation function is the difference of two monotone functions and similar results (e.g. the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), which is nearly always stated as monotone but has intervals where it is constant).

Comment: It may depend on the language, also.

Comment: Hi @TheSilverDoe - the language is English, probably US English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology here is a mess, as you've seen in the comments. The unambiguous terms are "strictly increasing" (which means the strict inequality, $x_n < x_{n+1}$) vs. "weakly increasing" or "nondecreasing" (which means $x_n \le x_{n+1}$); "monotonically increasing" could mean either of these depending on the author.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) seems to favor the meaning "nondecreasing."